# Cloud Custodian policy to stop EC2 instances containing a tag and not containing a tag value

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudcustodian

I want to stop EC2 instances which do not have a tag `ABC` and whose `tag(ABC)` value is not of type `@gmail.com`

I am trying to  use the cloud custodian policy in AWS, I have written like this

```yaml
  filters:
    - or:
      - "tag:ABC": absent
      - type: value
        key: "tag:ABC"
        op: ne
        value: '/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@gmail.com/'
  actions:
    - stop
```

However, this code does not have the desired effect. Any idea why?

Comment: Please have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created this policy using [special filters](https://www.cloudcustodian.io/docs/filters.html) example.

`ec2-without-gmail-in-tag.yml`

```yaml
policies:
  - name: ec2-without-gmail-in-tag
    description: |
      Stop EC2 instances that do not have a tag or if the tag exists but doesnt have a specific value
    resource: ec2
    filters:
      - or:
        # check if tag is absent
        - "tag:ABC": absent
        # or check if tag does not contain @gmail.com using a negative lookahead
        - type: value
          key: "tag:ABC"
          op: regex
          value: '^((?!@gmail.com).)*$'
```

You can test out this filter using python's `re` module.

```py
$ python

>>> import re

>>> regex = '^((?!@gmail.com).)*$'

>>> re.match(regex, 'Test if @gmail.com matches').group(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

>>> re.match(regex, 'Test if @gmail matches').group(0)
'Test if @gmail matches'
```